# Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: paypal

I started to get this error (as an usaul customer, when I try to order some products on IHERB and other site). In 2017 all worked ok.
I found this artical
https://www.paypal.com/il/selfhelp/article/ts2067

what I need to explain in the support of this sites?? They answered me that other people can buy via PP without problem. But why I m not? :(((
My error that I get from the both sites:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&token=EC-6RB11487FP568722H&country.x=GB&locale.x=en_GB#/checkout/genericError?code=REVGQVVMVA%3D%3D

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&token=EC-3NL51346KN821952W&country.x=RU&locale.x=ru_RU#/checkout/genericError?code=REVGQVVMVA%3D%3D

What I can do as a customer?
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from IHERB that it may be happens because my billing address in the PP is not the same as shipping address (my case).
Very stupid from my point of the view, but...
Even error not explain it, I needed to spend my time to find what the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Error is address on paypal : 'address_error' you  may need to fill out some address information and contact to paypal, there is no such code errors try sendbox to test your code if works follow the above instructions.